# How to sum a range with multiple criteria where the condition is met from another sheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have 3 sheets, a setup sheet, a transaction sheet, and a summary sheet.
Setup sheet is formatted as such,

| Account | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Acct_1 | Type_1 |
| Acct_2 | Type_1 |
| Acct_3 | Type_1 |
| Acct_4 | Type_2 |
| Acct_5 | Type_2 |
| Acct_6 | Type_2 |

Transaction Sheet

| Account | Amount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acct_1 | Cell 1 |  |
| Acct_2 | Cell 2 |  |
| Acct_5 | Cell 3 |  |
| Acct_6 | Cell 4 |  |
| Acct_4 | Cell 5 |  |
| Acct_3 | Cell 6 |  |

In the summary sheet I have a single cell that I want to sum up all transactions from the accounts with account type_2 before a selected date including the selected date. I know a vlookup can't do this. Any suggestions?

I've tried vlookup, and I got it to work by hard coding the wanted accounts in a sumifs, but I'd rather it update automatically, so if I add more accounts to the setup sheet.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide [minimal reproducible sample sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can replicate and better help you.

Answer (score 0):

## Formula

Assumes:

- `A1=lookup_type`
- `A2=lookup_date`

```
=LET(
   setup,setup!A:B,
   trans,transactions!A:C,
   type,A1, date,A2, 
   accts,FILTER(
     INDEX(setup,,1),
     INDEX(setup,,2)=type),
   SUM(
     FILTER(
       INDEX(trans,,2), 
       COUNTIF(
         accts, INDEX(trans,,1)), 
       1/(1/INDEX(trans,,3))<=date)))
```

- 1 is divided by the inverse of each date in the transaction list as a **minimal** check that there is a non-zero number (date) in the cell. Otherwise blanks and zeros would also pass the test `<=date`